# Store Collection of Object in Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want store collection of complex c# class in Redis
This collection has 2 type of usage:

- first retrieve all objects from collection
- second is retrieve specific item from collection by id

  1. What is the best Redis type for storing this type of data?
  2. Is it Ok to store c# object as byte array in Redis String, and when i need to this data deserialize it to my collection? , also if the rate of this data usage is high.

Dose exist any better solution for cache data for c#?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Redis Hashes](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) for your C# objects. Populate it with [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/HMSET):

```
HMSET objects:classname:id member1type member1value [member2type member2value]...
```

To get all objects, simply use [HGETALL](http://redis.io/commands/HGETALL), and to get a specific member, [HGET](http://redis.io/commands/HGET) (you can also use [HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/HMGET) to get more than one member).

Depands on your needs, you can also add sets with ids for each class, and than use [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/SORT) to get a specific member(s) from all stored class objects.